# WPF text editor with multiple (fixed) sub-sections

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to find a solution for the following scenario: users should be able to manually edit multi-line text in a control. However, the text should be split into multiple "sub-sections" as maintained by the software. User should still be able to select/copy&paste text fragments across sections, but should not be able to delete sections as illustrated below:
[image]
The ability to do this with rich-text formatting (at least bold/italics,...) would be nice, but is not mandatory.

I have been trying to figure out a way to accomplish this in WPF.

Just stacking separate textboxes does not allow users to select across sections.

Does anyone know if a control that does that (open source or commercial) or some strategy to do this as a custom control?

Any help is appreciated.